# newbie: lamp stack to dart vm

Tags: dart, lamp

This is a newbie question, I have not read any dart doc, I just saw the video from Google I/O 2013. My company has webapp using Linux apache mysql php. Say,my aim is to change it using dart vm, but slowly. Maybe I'll write dart, convert it to javascript. My questions:
1. can I replace the php part with dart (convert to js) while still using LAMP ?
2. if the dart vm already installed in a VPS, can client access it using other browsers beside chrome?

Hope this is the right place to ask the question.
Thank you

Comment: based on the extensive research you have done into dart, you're doomed

Comment: This should be asked on superuser.com or perhaps serverfault.com.  It's off topic here.

Comment: Are you talking about Dart in the browser or on the server, or both?
If you use Dart in the Browser then there is nothing special. Dart generates HTML/CSS output that you serve like any other static HTML/CSS file.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, you can replace PHP with Dart and run it via Apache. See [this article](http://news.dartlang.org/2012/05/run-dart-in-apache-web-server.html). There are some libraries to also enable connecting to MySQL (like [this one](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/sqljocky)).
2. The Dart VM is unrelated to client access; the Dart VM on the server would only be used for server-side Dart. Client-side Dart is generally converted into JavaScript using `dart2js` (via `pub build`) and this will work with all modern browsers.